# Log in to my Application via Identity Server using ORCID Credentials

Tags: authentication, orcid, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 and I would log in to my Application via Identity Server using [ORCID](https://orcid.org/) credentials. ORCID provides a [public API](https://members.orcid.org/api/about-public-api) and I can't understand how integrate it on Identity Server.

I would do something like that: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Logging+in+to+your+Application+via+Identity+Server+using+Facebook+Credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORCID seems to be supporting OAuth. In that case, you can configure ORCID as a federated OAuth identity provider in IS [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Federated+Authentication)[[2]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect). You'll have to register in ORCID and get a client key and secret and configure them in IS. [[3]](https://members.orcid.org/api/getting-started) & [[4]](https://members.orcid.org/api/oauth/3legged-oauth) might help.

Comment: yes, ORCID supports both OAuth and OpenID, so it mustn't be a problem. I just would know if there was something else to do.. thank you @Lucifer!